# how to make armature that acts the same across multiple objects

Tags: rigging, blender-internal-render-engine, bones

I mede this modle in blender and when I wanted to rig it the armature didnot move all of the objects that its assigned to the same, some moved more and some less.
my question is, how can you make so the armature moves all the objects equaly.

[image: all those strands should not be there.]

I attached the .blend file.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9PdIZgT3LGYajB5b3lXSWVpMW8

Comment: Could you provide your .blend file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com to be able to help you?

Comment: i added the .blend file in the post